# Use XML column instead of denormalization?

Tags: sql-server, xml

We have a database storing ~5m contacts, each with multiple addresses.

The DB is normalized, a separate Addresses-Table with FK to Contacts, properly indexed.
~10m Addresses.

Address again references Provinces & Countries tables.

Since this is a platform where one Contact is viewed at a time and no search is needed on Address properties (and if - we use Lucene.Net) .... would it make sense to just put the Address information into an XML field on the Contact?

```
<Addresses>
    <Address Street="" City="" ... />
    <Address Street="" City="" ... />
</Addresses>
```

Its not really denormalization - but still getting rid of 3 Joins (Address/Country/Province)

Or asked another way.... will 5mio records and 10mio records joined even put any strain on the database? (say for example with ~50 requests hitting the DB concurrently?)

Would it be premature optimization to do such a thing? (event when I'm absolutely sure that I will never query for Address properties...)

We are using SQL Server 2012

Comment: I would like to see this answered as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you use this column as nosql - just to store values and get whole data this solution can be used. But there are some limitations:

1. Hard to search data in this column (but possible)
2. Hard to modify data in this column (but possible)
3. You can't get part of data in this column using EF for example (just using stored procedures)
4. No foreing keys (you have to support data consistency yourself)

And you get this benefits:

1. Simple storage (one table with all data)
2. Simple queries

Shortly, yes, you can use this solution because you say you won't query part of this data or change it.